# How do I expose my dockerized container outside of my EC2 instance?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

How do I expose my docker container from outside of my EC2 instance?

```
version: '3.1' services:  php:   image: leonard/${CPROJECT}.php:tg1   build:    context: .    dockerfile: './docker/php/Dockerfile'   depends_on:
   - redis
   - mariadb   command:
   - /bin/bash
   - -c
   - umask 000 && ./php-fpm-build.sh && php-fpm   networks:
   - backend   volumes:
   - ./htomato.com/:/var/www/:consistent
   - ./htomato.com/node_modules/:/var/www/node_modules/:cached
   - ./htomato.com/vendor/:/var/www/vendor/:cached
   - ./logs/php/:/var/log/htomato/:cached

 apache:   image: leonard/common.apache:tg1   build: './docker/apache/'   depends_on:
   - php   networks:
   - frontend
   - backend
   - traefik   labels:
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache.rule=${HTTPRULE}
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache.service=${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache.entryPoints=web
   - traefik.http.services.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache.loadbalancer.server.port=80

   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-ssl.rule=${HTTPRULE}
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-ssl.entryPoints=websecure
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-ssl.service=${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-ssl
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-ssl.tls=true
   - traefik.http.services.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-ssl.loadbalancer.server.port=80

   - traefik.enable=true
   - traefik.docker.network=webgateway
   - traefik.port=80   volumes:
   - ./htomato.com/public:/var/www/public
   - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

 mariadb:   image: leonard/common.mariadb:tg1   build: './docker/mariadb/'   restart: always   environment:    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: A7h2ie23    MYSQL_DATABASE: ${CPROJECT}    MYSQL_USER: ${CPROJECT}    MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_PASS}    DBDUMP: ${DBDUMP}    DATABASE: ${CPROJECT}   volumes:
   - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
   - ./docker/mariadb/import-dump.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/a-import-dump.sh networks:
   - backend   ports:
   - ${MARIADB_DEVPORT}:3301

 redis:   image: redis   restart: always   networks:
   - backend

 varnish:   image: varnish:6.1   restart: always   depends_on:
   - apache   networks:
   - frontend
   - backend
   - traefik   volumes:
   - ./docker/varnish:/etc/varnish

 node:   image: leonard/node:8.17   build:    context: .    dockerfile: './docker/node/Dockerfile'

  networks:    backend:    traefik:   labels:
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp.rule=${HTTPRULE}
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp.entryPoints=gulp
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp.service=${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp
   - traefik.http.services.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp.loadbalancer.server.port=3000

   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp-ui.rule=${HTTPRULE}
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp-ui.entryPoints=gulp-ui
   - traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp-ui.service=${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp-ui
   - traefik.http.services.${COMPOSE_CPROJECT_NAME}-apache-gulp-ui.loadbalancer.server.port=3000

   - traefik.enable=true
   - traefik.docker.network=webgateway
   - traefik.port=80

  command:
   - /bin/bash
   - -c
   - umask 000 && npm ci; socat TCP-LISTEN:80,fork,reuseaddr TCP:apache:80 & make css-browser   volumes:
   - ./htomato.com:/htomato.com   working_dir: /htomato.com

volumes:  db-data:

networks:  frontend:  backend:  traefik:   external:    name: webgateway
```

The above is my docker-compose file. After I run it, I get:

I ran docker-compose up and I got:

```
Proxying: http:local.htomato.com:80
and Access URLs: Local: http://localhost:3000 External: http://0.0.0.0:30
```

The ec2 instance is accessible via staging.htomato.com port 22 through ssh, but how d I access localhost:3000 from outside? I was told all I needed to enter staging.htomato.com:3000 in the browser, but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose is all messed up from the formatting but I don't see a rule in your traefik routers which ties a domain to your container.

Traefik is a reverse proxy, you'll have to point all the domain names and subdomains to the Load Balancer or the Elastic IP address fronting the instance.

So for the first hope, ie from domain/to subdomain, the DNS mapping will cover the routing.

For the next hope ie, routing the request to the actual container, you'll need a Host rule.

see

So you'll probably need to pass

```
Host(`staging.htomato.com`)
```

to `${HTTPRULE}`

You don't need to provide the port as traefik acting as the reverse proxy and the port will not be exposed